# Unable to get mod_rewrite to rewrite URL's

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite, centos7

I'm having an issue with Apache not wanting to read my rewrite directives and actually rewrite my URLs based on those directives. I have the conditions and rules written directly into my Apache `httpd.conf` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} Round_2
  RewriteRule ^Round_2/(.*)$ /newBuyer/desktop/$1 [R=301,L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} itemList
  RewriteRule ^/?(.*)/itemList/(.*)$ /newBuyer/$1/search/$2 [R=301,L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} eventDetail
  RewriteRule ^/?(.*)/eventDetail/(.*)$ /newBuyer/$1/event/$2 [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

I have reloaded apache using:

```
$ apachectl -k graceful
```

flushed browser cache, and the redirect isn't working. I am able to get it to work on my local Windows Apache instance but not on my Cent7 instance of Apache.

I have confirmed the rewrite mod is loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding Directory tags after the IfModule between the conditions and rules, I was able to get the URL rewrite working. Here is the final working result:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        <Directory "/directory/to/designers/files/">
        RewriteEngine On

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} Round_2
        RewriteRule ^Round_2/(.*)$ /newBuyer/desktop/$1 [R=301,L]

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} itemList
        RewriteRule ^/?(.*)/itemList/(.*)$ /newBuyer/$1/search/$2 [R=301,L]

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} eventDetail
        RewriteRule ^/?(.*)/eventDetail/(.*)$ /newBuyer/$1/event/$2 [R=301,L]
        </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

Thank you

Comment: mod_rewrite works differently when used in a _directory_ (or `.htaccess`) context to when it is used directly in the server config (or virtual host) context. By wrapping these directives in a `<Directory>` container you are changing this context. When used directly in the server config, the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ matches against the full root-relative URL path (starting with a slash). (So, certainly, your first redirect would never match.) Whereas in a _directory_ context, `RewriteRule` matches against a _relative_ URL-path, less the directory-prefix, which notably excludes the slash prefix.